# How to count all records from selected table with empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have **four** tables that I have to select only **3** tables with a Database named **Records**

```
Records
1.Cases
2.Ballistics
3.Chem
4.Accounts

Cases
id|year|Natureofcase |
0 |    |Repact 1901a |
1 |2003|Repact 1907b |
3 |2004|Repact 1902  |

Ballistics
id|year|Name     |Type  |
0 |2003|         |a-101 | 
1 |    |Silver-A |a-202 |
3 |2005|Red Cap  |      |

Chem
id|year|Identified   |
0 |    |H20+C20      |
1 |2001|Am           |
3 |2009|             |
```

SO we have **6** rows with empty tables.
I want to display that sum **6** using PHP. Thank you. Any comments/answers/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i think you mean empty fields, right? not empty tables.

Comment: yes, empty fields Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cases WHERE year = '' OR Natureofcase = '') +
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ballistics WHERE year ='' OR Name='' OR Type='') +
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Chem WHERE year='' OR Identified='')
AS total_empty
```